# Mysql giving A comma or a closing bracket was expected (near "(" at position 109)

Tags: php, mysql

I just updated mysql and I don't see the missing bracket

```
CREATE TABLE payments 
(   id int(11) NOT NULL, 
    amount int(11) NOT NULL, 
    alloted datetime NOT NULL, 
    dateadded datetime NOT NULL, 
    modified datetime NOT NULL, 
    userid int(11) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO payments (`amount`,`alotted`, `dateadded`, `modified`, `userid`)
VALUES ( 100, DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTHS),NOW(),NOW(),139107 )
```

Comment: put here table schema to check datatypes

Comment: Why do you use ` ` ` for the column names?

Comment: If you can add the table creation script, it would be easier to re-create

Comment: CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `alloted` datetime NOT NULL,
  `dateadded` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: you getting error because DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTHS) in query so add \`\` and check i would work fine

Comment: Server version: 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-log - (Ubuntu)

Comment: interval 6 months should be interval 6 month.

Comment: #1292 - Incorrect datetime value: INSERT INTO gmi_payments_platzs (amount, alloted, dateadded, modified, userid)
VALUES ( 100, "DATE_ADD( NOW, INTERVAL 6 MONTHS)","NOW()","NOW()",139107 ) tried single quotes and back quotes

Comment: 18 errors were found during analysis.

A comma or a closing bracket was expected (near "(" at position 102)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "NOW" at position 104) with month instead of months

Comment: @user3308713 your question can't be changed. I rolled it back. My answer will make no sense. Don't fix typos in the question :p

Comment: If you are struggling with stuff, like, for whatever reason, you are typing comments about errors in another table, then ask another fresh question. We love fresh new questions :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had a typo near alloted. It is `MONTH` not `MONTHS`.

And the `id` column had no default value. So I made an `AUTO_INCREMENT`

And on the `INSERT`, those are called back-ticks folks. They are fine.

```
DROP TABLE payments;
CREATE TABLE payments 
(   id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    amount int NOT NULL, 
    alloted datetime NOT NULL, 
    dateadded datetime NOT NULL, 
    modified datetime NOT NULL, 
    userid int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO payments (`amount`,`alloted`, `dateadded`, `modified`, `userid`)
VALUES ( 100, DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH),NOW(),NOW(),139107 )
```